# How can you get input file to work in a WKWebView?

Tags: macos, swift, file, input, wkwebview

When you have a WKWebView in an OSX application, when you press a `<input type="file">` button, you can't select a file from your harddisk. How would you enable this feature?

I heard that normally you use:

```
func webView(sender: WebView!, runOpenPanelForFileButtonWithResultListener resultListener: WebOpenPanelResultListener!)
```

Which is part of the `WebUIDelegate` but altho you set `self.webView.UIDelegate = self` it does not get fired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug in WKWebView.

https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=137759

Comment: Thanks for your answer, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the 100% working solution for WKWebview "File Upload" Problem.

You just need to implement the UIDelegate:

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView runOpenPanelWithParameters:(WKOpenPanelParameters *)parameters initiatedByFrame:(WKFrameInfo *)frame completionHandler:(void (^)(NSArray<NSURL *> *URLs))completionHandler;
```

Follow this link for more description about this delegate:
[RunOpenPanel Delegate](https://developer.apple.com/reference/webkit/wkuidelegate/1641952-webview?language=objc)

Comment: This delegate method is no longer available it seems.

Comment: just now i checked the link, it is available. Note:- This is for OSX.

Comment: Aah, sad ... What is the solution for iOS then 

Comment: @HarishPathak did you find any solution for this issue?

Comment: @ahmedShoeib No solution, did it through POST API, using custom javascript call.