# Upload file using input type=file with WKWebView does not open file dialog

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, progressive-web-apps

I'm using Xcode 11.5 and loading a web page in a WKWebView. I have file access set to read only and this is my apps capability list.

[image]

This is how my `loadView` look like

```swift
    override func loadView() {
        //Inject JS string to read console.logs for debugging
        let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        let action = "var originalCL = console.log; console.log = function(msg){ originalCL(msg); window.webkit.messageHandlers.iosListener.postMessage(msg); }" //Run original console.log function + print it in Xcode console
        let script = WKUserScript(source: action, injectionTime: .atDocumentStart, forMainFrameOnly: false) //Inject script at the start of the document
        configuration.userContentController.addUserScript(script)
        configuration.userContentController.add(self, name: "iosListener")
        
        //Initialize WKWebView
        webView = WebView(frame: (NSScreen.main?.frame)!, configuration: configuration)
        
        //Set delegates and load view in the window
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        view = webView
    }
```

When I use Safari on iOS and tap the input type=file, the dialog opens up, but using my macOS app with a webView it does not work. Do I need to set more capabilities on my app? I found some old issues with file inputs but they seem to be resolved?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can you get input file to work in a WKWebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33059687/how-can-you-get-input-file-to-work-in-a-wkwebview)

Comment: @Willeke I use Swift 4 so I don't think this answers my question

Comment: Does "You just need to implement the UIDelegate" and a link to [RunOpenPanel Delegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkuidelegate/1641952-webview) answer your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implemented the UIDelegate like this.

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, runOpenPanelWith parameters: WKOpenPanelParameters, initiatedByFrame frame: WKFrameInfo, completionHandler: @escaping ([URL]?) -> Void) {
    let openPanel = NSOpenPanel()
    openPanel.canChooseFiles = true
    openPanel.begin { (result) in
        if result == NSApplication.ModalResponse.OK {
            if let url = openPanel.url {
                completionHandler([url])
            }
        } else if result == NSApplication.ModalResponse.cancel {
            completionHandler(nil)
        }
    }
}
```